# Having trouble removing and adding a class with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using animate.js and fullpage.js. My goal is to add a slideOutLeft animation when scrolling away from a section, and to add a slideInLeft animation when visiting a section.

My current code removes the slide in animation and applies the slide out animation, but never reapplies the slide in animation.

```js
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $('.text').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
  },
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    
    $('.text').removeClass('animated slideInLeft');  
 
    $('.text').addClass('animated slideOutLeft');  
    }
 
});
```

```css
#first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#second {
  background-color: blue;
}
.height {
height: 100vh;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.9/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section height" id="first">
      <h2 class="text">Something1</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="section height" id="second">
     <h2 class="text">Something2.</h2>
    
  </div>
  <div class="section height" id="third">
    <h2 class="text">Something else </h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if the answer is that you want, please give a tick and vote it up for other user that can find the solution easily

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't had a chance to test it yet but the snippet works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `onLeave`, you must use the leaving section to find the text and apply the `slideOutLeft` in `onLeave`. Also remember that remove the `slideOutLeft` in `afterLoad` which the text can slide it out again.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    $(this).find('.text').removeClass('animated slideOutLeft');
    $(this).find(".text").css("display","block");
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
  },
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    var leavingSection = $(this);
    $(leavingSection).find(".text").removeClass('animated slideInLeft');  

    $(leavingSection).find(".text").addClass('animated slideOutLeft');  
    }

});
```

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/39gadbnv/1/

Comment: @Tronald if the answer is that you want, please give a tick and vote it up for other user that can find the solution easily.